# Make name for multicolumn manipulating by mutate in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate some percentage for each columns in a Dataframe. I try to make name for each new column by getting column names and add some extra text by paste function.
Unfortunately it does not work. So what is the problem in the following code? Is there a better way to do this? (Consider that the real data have more than 300 columns).

```
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame(
  nt_1=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,-1),
  x1=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1),
  x2=c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1),
 x3=c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1),
  y1=c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1),
  y2=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1),
  y3=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1),
  nt_2=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,-1)
 )
df <-df %>%  mutate(
  total= select(., x1:y3) %>% rowSums())

df <-df %>%  mutate(
paste(names(df %>% select(x1:y3)),"prc",sep = "")=
(df %>% select(x1:x3)+df %>% select(y1:y3))/df$total)
```

Comment: You are looking for the `.names` argument to `mutate()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not so clear, but what about something like this to calculate rowwise percentage, and rename it?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 mutate(across(x1:y3, ~ . / rowSums(across(x1:y3))*100,.names = "percent_{col}"))

   nt_1 x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 nt_2 percent_x1 percent_x2 percent_x3 percent_y1 percent_y2 percent_y3
1     1  1  1  1  1  0  1    1   20.00000   20.00000   20.00000   20.00000    0.00000   20.00000
2     0  0  1  0  1  1  0    0    0.00000   33.33333    0.00000   33.33333   33.33333    0.00000
3     1  1  0  0  0  0  0    1  100.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000
4     0  0  1  1  1  1  1    0    0.00000   20.00000   20.00000   20.00000   20.00000   20.00000
5     0  0  1  1  1  1  0    0    0.00000   25.00000   25.00000   25.00000   25.00000    0.00000
6     1  1  1  0  1  0  0    1   33.33333   33.33333    0.00000   33.33333    0.00000    0.00000
7     1  1  0  0  0  1  0    1   50.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000   50.00000    0.00000
8     0  0  1  0  0  0  1    0    0.00000   50.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000   50.00000
9     0  0  0  0  0  1  0    0    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000  100.00000    0.00000
10   -1  1  1  1  1  1  1   -1   16.66667   16.66667   16.66667   16.66667   16.66667   16.66667
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prop.table function in base r.

```
new_df<-cbind(df, as.data.frame(prop.table(x = as.matrix(df), margin = 2)))

###percentage columns will be in ...# format because they are duplicated###
###Can keep or use gsub function###

gsub("\\...[:digit:]", "_percentage", names(new_df))
```